# Mysterious "media" volume mounted on desktop Mac OS X

Tags: mount, disk-utility, osx-mountain-lion

I have a mysterious volume mounted on my desktop that I can't seem to forcibly unmount. I've tried using umount and also diskutil, but it seems to automatically remount itself. I've copied my hdd with Time Machine, and copied it onto a new computer, and it also has the drive mounted on it. It's not pointing to anything and I can't open it, nor can I forcibily remove it by hand with rm -Rf.

Any ideas? I noticed this problem after I upgraded to Mountain Lion from Lion. It causes problems because when I try to select a file using the built in Finder dialog box, it freezes for a few minutes because it tries to cache or read into the "media" mounted volume.

[Picture of my desktop](http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/1429/screenshot20120903at102.png)

I added a picture so you guys can see what I'm talking about. It's a media volume that is mounted on my desktop, but I can't get it to go away and it really slows down my finder when I use it to select items.

Comment: Can you post the output of the 'mount' command?

Comment: Type mount and the path of the folder? What command you want me to run?

Comment: I tried running diskutil umount but it doesn't work: diskutil umount ./media 
Unmount successful for ./media

But the volume is still there.

Comment: just "mount" without parameters. It should print the list of mounted volumes

Comment: Hmm, it actually showed up, but not sure what it means:
map -static on /Users/allen/Desktop/media (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally got that mofo deleted! Thanks much for your help, Matteo! If you would have put up an answer, I would have give you the credit. All because of the mount command telling me some info, I did some google search. I had to open up Directory Utility, and I went to mounts and found a mount in there. I deleted that record and bam! The folder appeared back on my system and I could delete it!

Here is a post that relates to mine: [Permanently map a network drive on Mac OS X Leopard](https://superuser.com/questions/130787/permanently-map-a-network-drive-on-mac-os-x-leopard)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up terminal
2. Type in `diskutil list`

This should give you a brief overview of your devices

Here you may find more information about your mystery device

3. With it, there is a name. e.g Disk1, Disk7 etc. Note the one for your mystery device.
4. Type in `diskutil eject /dev/DiskX`

X being the number asigned to the device you want to remove

Comment: I don't see anything like that. I just se a table like this:

$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            419.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                80.2 GB    disk0s4

I just see /dev/disk0